# Error trying to access S3 from lambda(python)

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to access S3 from lambda(zappa+flask+python),

```
class Logicos ( ) :
  def newlogics() : 
     s3 = boto3.resource('s3') 
     return "It's Working"
```

I get the below error on line s3 = boto3.resource('s3'):

```
1571927898414] File "/var/task/newlogic_serverless.py", line 34, in newlogics


 [1571927898414] s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
[1571927898414] File "/var/runtime/boto3/__init__.py", line 100, in resource
[1571927898414] return _get_default_session().resource(*args, **kwargs)
[1571927898414] File "/var/runtime/boto3/session.py", line 389, in resource
[1571927898414] aws_session_token=aws_session_token, config=config)
[1571927898414] File "/var/runtime/boto3/session.py", line 263, in client
[1571927898414] aws_session_token=aws_session_token, config=config)
[1571927898414] File "/var/runtime/botocore/session.py", line 827, in create_client

[1571927898414] credentials = self.get_credentials()
[1571927898414] File "/var/runtime/botocore/session.py", line 426, in get_credentials
[1571927898414] 'credential_provider').load_credentials()
[1571927898414] File "/var/runtime/botocore/session.py", line 903, in get_component
[1571927898414] self._components[name] = factory()
[1571927898414] File "/var/runtime/botocore/session.py", line 145, in <lambda>
[1571927898414] lambda:  botocore.credentials.create_credential_resolver(self))
[1571927898414] File "/var/runtime/botocore/credentials.py", line 70, in create_credential_resolver
[1571927898414] container_provider = ContainerProvider()
[1571927898414] File "/var/runtime/botocore/credentials.py", line 1789, in __init__
[1571927898414] fetcher = ContainerMetadataFetcher()
[1571927898414] File "/var/runtime/botocore/utils.py", line 1238, in __init__
[1571927898414] timeout=self.TIMEOUT_SECONDS
[1571927898414] File "/var/runtime/botocore/httpsession.py", line 179, in __init__
[1571927898414] self._manager = PoolManager(**self._get_pool_manager_kwargs())
[1571927898414] File "/var/runtime/botocore/httpsession.py", line 187, in _get_pool_manager_kwargs
[1571927898414] 'ssl_context': self._get_ssl_context(),
[1571927898414] File "/var/runtime/botocore/httpsession.py", line 196, in _get_ssl_context
[1571927898414] return create_urllib3_context()
[1571927898414] File "/var/runtime/botocore/httpsession.py", line 71, in create_urllib3_context
[1571927898414] context.options |= options
[1571927898414] File "/var/lang/lib/python3.7/ssl.py", line 518, in options
[1571927898414] super(SSLContext, SSLContext).options.__set__(self, value)
[1571927898414] File "/var/lang/lib/python3.7/ssl.py", line 518, in options
[1571927898414] super(SSLContext, SSLContext).options.__set__(self, value)
[1571927898414] File "/var/lang/lib/python3.7/ssl.py", line 518, in options
[1571927898414] super(SSLContext, SSLContext).options.__set__(self, value)
[1571927898414] [Previous line repeated 477 more times]
[1571927898414] RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

but, If I run the same line of code without zappa It is working fine.

Please help on this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had installed gevent and that was causing the error .After uninstalling gevent ,it is working well

Comment: +1 this is SO incredible... I'd spent few hours yesterday till late in the night wondering about this, finally gave up and went to sleep... this morning came across this answer... just commented out eventlet.monkey_patch() and it started working. (Had used eventlet earlier in Flask with socketio - it had worked quite well, but now porting it to FastAPI)